# Is it known how the brain corrects the world-up-side-down-view of our eyes?

Tags: perception, cognitive-neuroscience

Because of our eye functioning as a camera obscura the light entering our pupils is hitting the retina of the eye in opposite directions. So what is left becomes right and right left and above becomes beneath and beneath becomes above.

So somewhere in our brains this image is turned back to the world how it is. But how and where is the brain that doing?